# Bash script to replace multi lines with new set of lines

Tags: bash

Quiet new to bash scripting, I have like 200 plus bash script files and I want to create a bash script which will replace certain lines of code with new set of line. Since large no of files present can't do it one by one so, may a list containing all files directories path in that script and while running it replaces in all files

```
#!/bin/bash
#config
FROM="logs@example.com"
FROMNAME="LOGS"
USER="diago"
PASS="*****"
APIKEY="*****"
***
*****
curl --request POST \
--url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '${APIKEY} \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "'${TO}'","name": 
"'${TONAME}'"}]}],"from": {"email": "'${FROM}'","name": 
"'${FROMNAME}'"},"subject": "'${SUBJECT}'","content": [{"type": 
"text/html", "value": "'${BODYHTML}'"}]}'
****
****
```

Here, I want to replace the particular line --header "Content-Type: application/json" \ to --header 'Content-Type: application/json' [double quotes to single quote only for this line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sed](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html)'s `c` command is right for this. See this example:

```
$ cat file
line 1
line foo
...
line bar
line N
$
$ cat foo.sh
sed -e '/line foo/,/line bar/c\
NEW LINE foo\
...\
...\
NEW LINE bar
' file
$
$ bash foo.sh
line 1
NEW LINE foo
...
...
NEW LINE bar
line N
$
```

Comment: Can you share pls any resource example will be more useful? plus this is for 1 file right(foo.sh)? where I can include for all the file paths?(like list of paths?)

Comment: that worked and printed changes in the terminal, but how to make those changes directly on the bash file?

Comment: updated the answer and added link to sed's manual. to edit the file in-place, use `-i` (be careful). and use a loop to iterate over multiple files.

Comment: I have a issue, if you look at the script above it contains variables like ${APIKEY}, ${TO} so when I just replace whole curl with new lines it's excepting actual values for ${APIKEY}, etc.. but those values are hard-coded in the script itself and it's dynamic, how to make it working?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean. could you give a [repro]?

Comment: sorry for the confusion,  forget about above...I have this line in bash script --header "Content-Type: application/json" \ and I want to convert it into --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ [double quotes to single quotes] from what I have seen there are solutions for global change in the file but I only want to change for this particular line